# JHipster: Long running REST service

Tags: jhipster

I have used JHipster to create a microservices application. One of my microservices has a REST api that takes a long time to return resource back to the angular client.  Due to this, the angular client doesn't wait for the response and simply does nothing.

Is there a property to set either on the angular side or on the server side to increase the timeout so that the front end "entity" $resource call waits till the backend REST service returns data?

**Update to provide additional information:**
In my REST method I commented out the actual DB call to fetch data from database. I have added a Sleep of 5 seconds and then sending a dummy object back to the angular front end. If the Sleep is <= 4 seconds then I receive the dummy data at the front end. If it's more than 4 seconds then the front end just doesn't receive anything (or doesn't wait for the REST response) ...

Not sure if there's any setting to tell angular to wait till the REST service responds back no matter what ..??

Here's my REST method ...

```
@GetMapping("/history-report-mms")
@Timed
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getAllHistoryReportMMS() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all HistoryReportMMS");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("foo", "bar");
    list.add(map);        
    return list;
    //return historyReportMMSService.findAll();
}
```

Here's my front end code ...

(function() {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('mmsFrontEndGatewayApp')
    .controller('HistoryReportMMSController', HistoryReportMMSController);

HistoryReportMMSController.$inject = ['HistoryReportMMS', 'HistoryReportMMSSearch'];

function HistoryReportMMSController(HistoryReportMMS, HistoryReportMMSSearch) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.historyReportMMS = [];
    vm.clear = clear;
    vm.search = search;
    vm.loadAll = loadAll;

    loadAll();

    function loadAll() {
        HistoryReportMMS.query(function(result) {
            vm.historyReportMMS = result;
            vm.searchQuery = null;
        });
    }

    function search() {
        if (!vm.searchQuery) {
            return vm.loadAll();
        }
        HistoryReportMMSSearch.query({query: vm.searchQuery}, function(result) {
            vm.historyReportMMS = result;
            vm.currentSearch = vm.searchQuery;
        });
    }

    function clear() {
        vm.searchQuery = null;
        loadAll();
    }    }})();
```

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is in client and not in zuul/ribbon settings on gateway? registry is not involved here, you should delete it from tags. How long is your request taking? Maybe you should not implement a synchronous web API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The request takes around 3 minutes.

Comment: This is very long, have you considered making asynchronous requests  http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/